# How can I compare two tables and delete the duplicate rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicate-data

I have two tables and I need to remove rows from the first table if an exact copy of a row exists in the second table.

Does anyone have an example of how I would go about doing this in MSSQL server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, at some point you're going to have to check all the columns - might as well get joining...

```
DELETE a
FROM a  -- first table
INNER JOIN b -- second table
      ON b.ID = a.ID
      AND b.Name = a.Name
      AND b.Foo = a.Foo
      AND b.Bar = a.Bar
```

That should do it... there is also `CHECKSUM(*)`, but this only *helps* - you'd still need to check the actual values to preclude hash-conflicts.

Comment: This works nicely as long as none of the columns contains nulls.  As soon as that happens, you have to start messing with complex conditions like (a.Name = b.Name OR (a.Name IS NULL AND b.Name IS NULL)) for each nullable column.  Another reason to shun nulls.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, If table `a` and table `b` present in the `view`. Then how can I delete the duplicate rows and keep original once? I have posted  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065340/sql-server-2008-r2-delete-duplicate-rows-from-tables-containing-in-view/32065972?noredirect=1#comment52032907_32065972] on such situation.

Comment: Using INTERSECT and EXCEPT (see other answer) for these types of operations avoids the NULL problem http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you're using SQL Server 2005, you can use [intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx):

```
delete * from table1 intersect select * from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the psuedocode below would do it..

```
DELETE FirstTable, SecondTable
FROM FirstTable
FULL OUTER JOIN SecondTable
ON FirstTable.Field1 = SecondTable.Field1
... continue for all fields
WHERE FirstTable.Field1 IS NOT NULL
AND SecondTable.Field1 IS NOT NULL
```

Chris's INTERSECT post is far more elegant though and I'll use that in future instead of writing out all of the outer join criteria :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try a DISTINCT query and do a union of the two tables.

You can use a scripting language like asp/php to format the output into a series of insert statements to rebuild the table the resulting unique data.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.name = t2.name WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```