# SQL Server 2008 R2: Delete duplicate rows from tables containing in view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

--Creating Table dup1

```
CREATE TABLE dup1
(
    cola VARCHAR(10),
    colb VARCHAR(10)
);
```

--Insertion of records

```
INSERT INTO dup1 VALUES('1','2');
INSERT INTO dup1 VALUES('1','2');
INSERT INTO dup1 VALUES('1','3');
INSERT INTO dup1 VALUES('1','4');
INSERT INTO dup1 VALUES('1','5');
```

--Creating Table dup2

```
CREATE TABLE dup2
(
    cola VARCHAR(10),
    colb VARCHAR(10)
);
```

--Insertion of records

```
INSERT INTO dup2 VALUES('1','2');
INSERT INTO dup2 VALUES('1','2');
INSERT INTO dup2 VALUES('2','3');
INSERT INTO dup2 VALUES('2','4');
INSERT INTO dup2 VALUES('1','5');
```

--Creating View

```
CREATE VIEW V_Dup as
SELECT * FROM dup1 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM dup2;
```

**Note**: The records `1,2` and `1,5` is duplicate in both tables **BUT** want to keep the original data.

My question is how do I delete the duplicate records from both tables.

Comment: You could use either a cursor, write the IDs to be delete into a temporary table. The use of DELETE FROM will only work for one of the tables - you need to capture the ID before you delete then. An identity key on both tables would help to.

Comment: @PeterSmith, Can you please answer it by using `CURSOR` how can I delete the records from tables which are in view?

Comment: can you please clarify, do you want to delete the duplicate records from one table or from both. If from only one table, which one. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSmith, I want to delete it from both tables if it found as duplicate and want to keep original one.

Comment: @PeterSmith, After deletion, the table dup1 contains (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5) and table dup2 should contains only (2,3),(2,4). I hope you got it now. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What is the final result in both tables, one record `'1','2'` in both, one record in total or no record? `'1','5'` is also a duplicate which appears in both tables, what should happen with it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Shall I edit my post? or Post a new one?

Answer (score 1):

create temp. table :

```
DECLARE @tempDuplicateTable AS TABLE(
    cola VARCHAR(10),
    colb VARCHAR(10)
)
```

insert row duplicate :

```
INSERT INTO @tempDuplicateTable
    ( cola, colb )
    (
        SELECT a.cola, a.colb FROM dup1 a
        INNER JOIN dup2 b ON b.cola = a.cola AND b.colb = a.colb
    )
```

delete duplicate data from both table dup1 and dup2 :

```
DELETE a FROM dup1 a INNER JOIN @tempDuplicateTable b ON b.cola = a.cola AND b.colb = a.colb
DELETE a FROM dup2 a INNER JOIN @tempDuplicateTable b ON b.cola = a.cola AND b.colb = a.colb
```

if you just want this result :

```
 cola   colb
   1    2
   1    3
   1    4
   1    5
   2    3
   2    4
```

try this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM V_Dup
```

or you can modify your View like this :

```
CREATE VIEW V_Dup as
    SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM (
    SELECT * FROM dup1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM dup2
) a
```

Comment: last part of your answer does the same as SELECT * FROM dup1 UNION SELECT * FROM dup2

Comment: @Irfan Kertianto, I have both tables in the view. How can I delete it from view which effects on all tables contained in the view? The last part of your answer is right but I have already created view with `UNION ALL` in this case how can I delete it?

Comment: @MAK The view just in "view". You cannot modify/delete data in View. If you want to modify data from both tables dup1 and dup2 such as remove duplicate data, you can create the logic for remove redundant data into Store Procedure. [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqldbauk/2011/07/11/can-you-delete-from-a-view_3F00_/)
If you have already created view with UNION ALL, you can change it view with "ALTER VIEW"

Comment: @MAK: [You can't delete from a  view if that contains more than table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqldbauk/2011/07/11/can-you-delete-from-a-view_3F00_/). You can delete from the underlying tables and join to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table with the rows need to be deleted from `CTE` and delete those from both the tables.

**Query**

```
CREATE TABLE dup1
(
    cola VARCHAR(10),
    colb VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO dup1 VALUES('1','2');
INSERT INTO dup1 VALUES('1','2');
INSERT INTO dup1 VALUES('1','3');
INSERT INTO dup1 VALUES('1','4');
INSERT INTO dup1 VALUES('1','5');

CREATE TABLE dup2
(
    cola VARCHAR(10),
    colb VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO dup2 VALUES('1','2');
INSERT INTO dup2 VALUES('1','2');
INSERT INTO dup2 VALUES('2','3');
INSERT INTO dup2 VALUES('2','4');
INSERT INTO dup2 VALUES('1','5');

CREATE VIEW V_Dup as
SELECT * FROM dup1 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dup2;

;with cte as 
(
    select rn=row_number() over
    (
        partition by cola,colb
        order by cola,colb
    ),*
    from V_Dup
)
select * into #temp
from cte 
where rn>1;

delete t1 from dup1 t1
inner join  #temp t2
on t1.cola = t2.cola
and t1.colb = t2.colb;

delete t1 from dup2 t1
inner join  #temp t2
on t1.cola = t2.cola
and t1.colb = t2.colb;

drop table #temp;
```

Comment: This delete's the original records also. But I need to delete the duplicate only.

Comment: @MAK your question ask "how do I delete duplicates from BOTH tables".  You didn't specify that you wanted to keep some of the duplicates

Comment: @t-clausen.dk : Yes. He didn't mention that.

Comment: @Ullas, I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want just to see record once in your view because you say you want to keep original data. So you should use UNION  instead of UNION ALL in your view

```
CREATE VIEW V_Dup as
SELECT * FROM dup1 UNION  
SELECT * FROM dup2;
```

Otherwise if you want to delete all the duplicated rows from table generating view you will have to do something like this:

```
;WITH DUP_CTE AS
(
SELECT  cola, colb,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cola,colb ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RN FROM V_Dup 
)
DELETE FROM DUP_CTE

WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 0 FROM dup_cte AS c WHERE c.cola=dup_cte.cola AND c.colb=dup_cte.colb AND RN <> 1);
```

If you want to delete only duplicates:

```
;WITH DUP_CTE AS
    (
    SELECT  cola, colb,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cola,colb ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RN FROM V_Dup 
    )
    DELETE FROM DUP_CTE
    WHERE  RN <> 1;
```

But you will need a primary key in your tables for the last two solutionz.

Comment: Can I update view `V_Dup` like the way you have used in `CTE`?

Comment: Are dup1 and dup2 partitionable table? I mean if you can add a column to them that allows to understand wich table to update. 
e.g. date so that if you insert a date in an interval you update dup1 else dup2

Answer (score 0):

Are dup1 and dup2 partitionable table? I mean if you can add a column to them that allows to understand wich table to update. 
e.g. date so that if you insert a date in an interval you update dup1 else dup2. If you don't have a partitioning column you could create one simply adding a column able to identify the table (e.g. a varchar(1) with value '1' or an int having value 1 for dup1 and 2 for dup2) . This column should be a part of the primary key (here I created an ID). The table could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.dup1
    (
    cola   VARCHAR (10),
    colb   VARCHAR (10),
    ID     INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    partit NCHAR (10) CONSTRAINT DF_dup1_partit DEFAULT ('1') NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_dup1 CHECK ([PARTIT]='1'),
    CONSTRAINT PK_dup1 PRIMARY KEY (ID, partit)
    )

CREATE TABLE dbo.dup2
    (
    cola   VARCHAR (10),
    colb   VARCHAR (10),
    ID     INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    partit NCHAR (10) CONSTRAINT DF_dup2_partit DEFAULT ('2') NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_dup2 CHECK ([PARTIT]='2'),
    CONSTRAINT PK_dup2 PRIMARY KEY (ID, partit)
    )
```

So that the view will be:

```
CREATE VIEW V_Dup as
SELECT * FROM dup1 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM dup2
WITH CHECK OPTION
```

this way you will be able to use the code I posted before